# Connect to Sharepoint server via WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, web, sharepoint, client

I inherited a large .NET server application which contains code that is supposed to connect to a Sharepoint server. I know this code worked when the original developer wrote it, and it still works on the client's production machine, but fails with an authentication error ("The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system") when I run it on my workstation for development.

The Sharepoint code uses a WebClient. The relevant lines are these:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
client.Credentials = GetSharePointCredentials();
```

The function "GetSharePointCredentials" returns an instance of ICredentials that is constructed from a username and a password. I know the username and password are correct, because I can go to the Sharepoint site in a web browser and log in with them.

I tried saying client.UseDefaultCredentials = true, but I didn't really expect it to work since my workstation is not signed on to any Windows domain that is associated with the Sharepoint server.

I do notice that the Sharepoint web application does a two-factor authentication when I log in that way (it sends a text message to the phone number of the account, which I have access to) and I suspect this might be part of the problem, although I think the X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED header is supposed to allow it to work without the phone number verification.

Unfortunately I am not the administrator of the Sharepoint instance or the domain, so I can't directly view or change their configuration, although I could ask someone for help if necessary.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my code was fine, but my IP address was being blocked by a firewall rule.